# Modularization: Use config.yaml file from GitHub repository for module

Tags: snakemake, pypsa

I want to use an existing `snakemake` workflow (`technology_data`) as a `module` into another workflow (let's call it `w`). At the moment I manually download (whenever the workflow is setup new) the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/pypsa/technology-data) of `technology_data` into the desired location and have it included into `w` as a subworkflow.

Now I want to include `technology_data` as-is, i.e. including the `config.yaml` that is contained in the GitHub repository into workflow `w` as a `module`.

What I have in my `Snakefile` of workflow `w` for now is:

```
module technology_data:
    snakefile: github("PyPSA/technology-data", path="Snakefile", commit="5a10981")

use rule * from technology_data as technology_data_*
```

Which fails when I call one of the rules of the workflow with the following error:

```
> snakemake -call technology_data_compile_cost_assumptions
...
WorkflowError in line 2 of https://github.com/PyPSA/technology-data/raw/5a10981/Snakefile:
Workflow defines configfile config.yaml but it is not present or accessible
```

I don't want to download the `config.yaml` from the repository but I want `Snakemake` to handle it automatically with the rest of the remote module.

I tried in the module definition to use:

- `configfile: github("PyPSA/technology-data", path="config.yaml", commit="5a10981")`
  which did not work (`configfile` is not understood by `module`)
- `config: snakemake.io.load_configfile(github("PyPSA/technology-data", path="config.yaml", commit="5a10981"))` which doesn't work either

Is there a good solution to have `snakemake` use the remote `config.yaml` automatically?